# Git: how do you resurrect a deleted file, since a move?

Tags: git

I need to recover a file that was deleted. Since the time it was deleted, the directory it was in has moved. Accordingly, when I try to check it out again, git complains:

```
error: pathspec '.../file_that_was_deleted.py' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

How do I get the file back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to recover the file when I made the old directory it was originally deleted in. They were empty directories. Then I moved it to the new location.

```
git checkout af0228b .../file_that_was_deleted.py
git mv file_that_was_deleted.py ../new_location_of_said_file/
```